# Python os.listdir() returning the parent directory list

Tags: python, directory-structure

Hello everybody! I have a really straight forward question.

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
|- folder1
|   |- folder1_1
|   |   |- ...
|   |- other_file.py
|   |- test.py
|- folder2
|   |- ...
|- file.py
```

In `test.py` I call

```
os.listdir()
```

and what I'm getting back is:

```
['folder1', 'folder2', 'file.py']
```

while I was expecting to get

```
['folder1_1', 'other_file.py', 'test.py']
```

as I was calling it inside `test.py`, I thought it would "list the current directory" from where I'm calling (as the documentation says that default parameter `path='.'` for the function). Or am I missing something?

Comment: `listdir()` probably starts looking at the current python path. It seems like that is the upper level in your example. Try navigating to the directory containing the file `test.py` directly and run it. You should probably get the correct path then. This is guessing without actually trying. Please post runnable code otherwise to help us follow your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory depends on where you launched your python script from.

So if you run from the root folder of your project:

```sh
python3 folder1/test.py
```

You will get `['folder1', 'folder2', 'file.py']`.

Instead if you run from `folder1` you will get the result you expected:

```sh
cd folder1
python3 test.py
```

To get the path of the file running some function you can rely on the `__file__` variable:

```py
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then you can use that as parameter for `os.listdir`

Comment: Thank you, Matteo. This makes a lot of sense. That raises me the following question then: how can I obtain the "current directory" relative to the file that's executing the call?